# What's this type of Closure supposed to mean and how does it work?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Got it from [Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2234250)

The Ultimate Closure
    Finally, for the ultra parsimonious there is the following, without a byte wasted.

```
let testEquality9 : (Int, Int) -> Bool = (==)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions decalred with the `func` keyword are just closures with names. `==` is an example of one such named function. It takes 2 `Int` arguements, and returns a `Bool` telling you if they're equal. Its type is `(Int, Int) -> Bool`

testEquality9 is a closure, with the type `(Int, Int) -> Bool`. To it, the closure of the `==` function is assigned.

It can be called like this:

```
testEquality9(1, 2) // false
testEquality9(1, 1) // true
```

The key thing to draw from this is that functions are really just closures, so they can be used everywhere closures can be used.

For example, if you wanted to sort an array of Ints, you could use:

```
let ints = [3, 1, 4, 2]
let sorted = ints.sort{$0 < $1}
```

The [`sort(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_MutableCollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/MutableCollectionType/s:FEsPs21MutableCollectionType4sortFFTWx9Generator7Element_WxS0_S1___SbGSaWxS0_S1___) method takes a closure that's of type `(Int, Int) -> Bool`. Our closure {$0 < $1} takes 2 `Int` params, and returns a `Bool`. So it fits that signiture.

However, we can make this code shorter. Because the [`<`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFsoi1lFTSiSi_Sb) operator's function already has type `(Int, Int) -> Bool`, we can write this:

```
let sorted = ints.sort(<)
```

This passes the function (named closure) `<` in directly, without explicitly making our own closure to wrap around it.

Comment: There was something wrong with my playground I guess. Got it to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a closure, it's the equality operator that compares two integers stored into a variable.

Every operator is defined using a function and that function can be assigned to a variable. There is nothing else to it.

Comment: Could you please show me a demo of what all I can do using this technique and is it advised to use this in our code?

Answer (score 0):

Operator Overloading:

```
func == (i : Int, j: Int) -> Bool {
     return i == j
}
```

Should be equivalent to that.

Comment: I don't seem to understand. Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, it's the abbreviation form of:

```
let testEquality9: (Int, Int) -> Bool = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Bool in return a == b }
```

Reading from right to left, it creates a function that compares two Ints and assigns it to the constant testEquality9.

You need to mentally separate the 3 pieces:

The constant name:

```
let testEquality9
```

The constant type (it's a function type):

```
(Int, Int) -> Bool
```

And the value assigned to the constant:

```
(==)
```

OR, the long version:

```
{ (a: Int, b: Int) -> Bool in return a == b }
```

Enjoy Swift :)